# Kiel oni mallongigas tempajn unuojn?

Tags: nouns

Kiel oni mallongigas *sekundo, minuto, horo, semajno, monato* kaj *jaro*? En la angla estas *sec, min, h, w, mo,* kaj *yr* laŭ mi scio. Kio pri en Esperanto?

Answer (score 3):

Mi scias ke almenaj kelkaj el tiuj ja havas kutimajn mallongigojn.

Oni povis indiki la aĝon de infano tiel:

- Mi havas tri infanojn, Adamo (5j), Karlo (4j), kaj Gretil (3j).

Jaro (j.) kaj jarcento (jc.) troviĝas en la jena listo.

http://www.kafejo.com/lingvoj/auxlangs/eo/mallongi.htm

En la diskuto pri la horo, oni klarigis ke eblas diri la horon tiel

- 3h15 - la tria horo kaj dek kvin.

Mi iom dubas cxu la aliaj havas vaste konatajn mallongigojn.

Answer (score 1):

PIV donas nur *s* por ”sekundo” kaj *min* por ”minuto”. Do eble ni inventu la ceterajn?

Jen ideo: *s, min, h, sem, mon, j*.

Aŭ eĉ: *s, min, hr, sem, mon, jr*.

Comment: Mi kredas ke oni ne respondu en Esperanto Stack Exchange per nuraj elpensajxoj.

Comment: Bone, mi respektas vian opinion. Laŭ mia sperto ekzistas kutimo inter Esperantistoj inventi novajn vortojn – ekz-e tiel ekiĝis la vorto ”mojosa” por Angla *cool*; kaj mi do eble iel tro rapide sentis tiun emon. :-)